# DropDownList showing 4 decimal places when Database only has 1 decimal place C# MVC Postgres

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, html-select, data-annotations

In my Postgres DB, I have a column for vatrate with the following values

9, 23, 0 and 13.5

They are set as numeric, with only 1 decimal place, and my ViewModel has the following annotation for that FK column

```
   //for vat rate  
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.#}",  ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Guid? vat_guid { get; set; }
```

In my view I have the following code for the dropdownlist

```
   @Html.DropDownList("vat_guid", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In my controller I have

```
   ViewBag.vat_guid = new SelectList(db.q_vat, "vat_guid", "q_rate", pagedProduct.SingleOrDefault().vat_guid);
```

But now my view result for the value with a decimal place is adding 3 extra 0s to that value, and I cannot find whats causing this issue

[Dropdownlist on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alw5J.png)

Comment: `[DisplayFormat]` is only applicable to `EditorFor()`. How are you generating the SelectList in the controller.

Comment: with this line 
       ViewBag.vat_guid = new SelectList(db.q_vat, "vat_guid", "q_rate", pagedProduct.SingleOrDefault().vat_guid); . I have updated question to include controller code.

Comment: Build your SelectList using `db.q_vat.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Value = x.vat_guid, Text = x.q_rate.ToString("0:0.#") });`

Comment: How do I update the line in the view, after building the list your way I am now getting following error
"There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'vat_guid'."

Comment: Of all the possible ways to generate a `<select>` you have chosen the worst possible one. And for that error refer [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o). Your editing data so the first step is always create a view model.

Comment: I will have a look at that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.0}",  ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Guid? vat_guid { get; set; }
```

Comment: did you try     "{0:0.0}"

Comment: Read the first comment in the question!